# Can a person work on two user accounts simultaneously

Tags: windows, user-accounts, multiple-users, user-management

Can I run two user accounts simultaneously in windows and work simultaneously? I have windows 7, 8.1 and 10.

I have got few applications (calling and remote tracking software) that I use everyday in the same time in different computers and I have to check two monitors. If I can run two different user accounts in one computer then I will have to check only one screen. I want to run them parallel.

Comment: There might be a simpler way, but you could use one session in a virtual machine.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding... if they're on different computers, why not just remote desktop into the other machine(s) and runt he RDP session(s) windowed so you can see the relevant parts of each screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really have two separate accounts 'logged in', other than fast user-switching.  But it depends on what you mean by logged in of course.

You can easily run applications as another user.

If you right click while holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> keyboard key on a shortcut or executable file you will be given the option to '**Run as a different user**'. Provide the required credentials, and the program will start.  You could start a Powershell or CMD window as another user. Any program you launch from those shells will run as the alternate user.

This mostly works with a few exceptions for applications designed to only allow a single running instance on a computer (Firefox, Chrome, Sublime Text, etc).

Comment: `You can easily run applications as another user` Note for interest: That operation is called **User Impersonation**.